# BigDecimal optimal scale for encoding

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, bigdecimal

I need to encode a `BigDecimal` compactly into a `ByteBuffer` to replace my current (rubbish) encoding scheme (writing the `BigDecimal` as a UTF-8 encoded `String` prefixed with a byte denoting the `String` length).

Given that a `BigDecimal` is effectively an integer value (in the mathematical sense) and an associated scale I am planning to write the scale as a single byte followed by a [VLQ encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) integer.  This should adequately cover the range of expected values (i.e. max scale 127).

My question: When encountering large values such as 10,000,000,000 it is clearly optimal to encode this as the value: 1 with a scale of -10 rather than encoding the integer 10,000,000,000 with a scale of 0 (which will occupy more bytes).  How can I determine the optimal scale for a given `BigDecimal`? ... In other words, how I can determine the minimum possible scale I set assign a `BigDecimal` without having to perform any rounding?

Please do not reference the term "premature optimisation" in your answers :-)

Comment: I won't, because I call it Premature Optimi*z*ation :-)

Comment: Well at least you didn't edit my queztion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[BigDecimal#stripTrailingZeros](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) seems to be doing this.